# lookup not joining with a collection

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongo playground to join two collections and expecting the result as below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "id": 1,
    "name": "so1",
    "sop": [{
      "id": "sop1",
      "value": "sopValue"
    }],
    "sops": [
      {
        "id": "sop1",
        "name": "sopName"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The mongo playground code is available here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tg-4aAk-O1e
Thank you for helping a newbie.

Comment: use `$in` instead like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SBec5FP4F7j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality Match with a Single Join Condition

```
db.so.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "sop",
      localField: "sops.id",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "sop"
    }
  }
])
```

Or the pipeline equivalent as mentioned by Ray:

```
db.so.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "sop",
      "let": {
        "sops_id": "$sops.id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              $in: [
                "$id",
                "$$sops_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "sop"
    }
  }
])
```